# shinyApp with ui and server in separate files?

Tags: r, shiny

Right now my shinyApp is running with four separate R files. app.R, server.R, ui.R, and global.R. This apparently is an old way of doing things but I like how it organizes my code.

I need to use the `onStart` parameter in the `shinyApp()` function. Because of the way I've separated my files, it looks like R knows to load the four files together when running the Run App button in R Studio. This means my app.R file only contains `runApp()`.

I can't seem to use the onStart parameter with `runApp()`. And when I try to create a `shinyApp(ui, server, onStart = test())` object and pass it through `runApp()` it can't find the test function.

```
### in global.R
test <- function(){
  message('im working')
}
```

```
### in app.R
app <- shinyApp(ui, server, onStart = test())

runApp(app)
```

I found this in the R documentation. I'm not sure what they mean by using the global.R file for this?

[image]

https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/shinyApp.html

Thanks a ton, I hope this question makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the functionality you want can be achieved by both `shinyAppDir` and `shinyApp`. You just have to use them correctly.
If you have the 3 file structure namely, `ui.R`, `server.R`, and `global.R`. You should use `shinyAppDir` and not `shinyApp`. In `global.R`, you can define code you want to run globally, if it's in a function, you can define and then call that function inside the same file i.e. `global.R`. In order to run it using `shinyAppDir`, you need to give the directory where your application files are placed.

According to the same `shinyApp` reference you shared,

```
shinyAppDir(appDir, options = list())
```

If you want to use `shinyApp` instead, you need to have both `ui` and `server` inside the same file, and pass the *object name* to `shinyApp` function. Here, if you want to run some code globally, you need to first have that code defined inside a function *in the same file*, and then pass that function *name* as the `onStart` parameter. If your function name is `test` you need to pass it as `shinyApp(ui, server, onStart = test)` and not `test()`, but more importantly, you need to have all 3 (`ui`, `server`, and your global function i.e. `test`) inside the same file.

According to reference,

```
shinyApp(ui, server, onStart = NULL, options = list(),   uiPattern = "/", enableBookmarking = NULL)
```